# Basic question on linear regression

Tags: linear-regression

I am trying to understand linear regression. The typical model takes form
$$y_{i}=ax_{i} +b + \epsilon_{i}, \ \ \ i=1..N$$  where   $\epsilon_{i}$, is an i.i.d Gaussian random variable. The objective is to minimize $$\sum_{i=1}^{N} (y_{i} - ax_{i} – b - \epsilon_{i})^{2}.$$

The computation of the gradient yields to:
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial a} = -\sum_{i=1}^{N}  y_{i} x_{i} + a\sum_{i=1}^{N}  x_{i}^{2} +b \sum_{i=1}^{N}  x_{i} + \sum_{i=1}^{N}  x_{i}\epsilon_{i}$$
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial b} = -\sum_{i=1}^{N}  y_{i} + a\sum_{i=1}^{N}  x_{i} +bN + \sum_{i=1}^{N}  \epsilon_{i}$$
My question concerns the terms involving $\epsilon_{i}$. What are the arguments that allow us to state that these terms are equal to zero?

Comment: They are not zero, but they vanish upon taking expectations of both sides. This is appropriate because you are looking for an unbiased estimator for $a,b$ anyway. (Look up the Gauss-Markov theorem, which is really the connection between "linear algebra" least squares and "statistics" least squares.)

Answer (score 0):

Usually we assume $\epsilon\sim N(0,\sigma^2)$, so $E[\epsilon]=0$ and if sample size is large enough $\sum^N\epsilon = NE[\epsilon]=0$